# c read udp data from a already used port

Tags: c, network-programming, udp, tcp

I have been using the code example given in

[How to read the UDP data payload coming from a port using C program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31686628/how-to-read-the-udp-data-payload-coming-from-a-port-using-c-program)

for reading udp data from the 5000 port.

However in my machine this port is used by another process and I know it. What I want to know is a solution to keep the c code receiving data from the port even if it is used from the other process.

Thank you guy for your help.

Answer (score 3):

No, basically you cannot open a UDP port which was used by another process already, unless all the sockets bound to and to bind to the same port has option SO_REUSEPORT set.

Whithout SO_REUSEPORT option being set, your second binding to the used port will fail with error code being EINVAL, See manual of [bind(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html)

> EINVAL The socket is already bound to an address.

For option SO_REUSEPORT, you can refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388706/socket-options-so-reuseaddr-and-so-reuseport-how-do-they-differ-do-they-mean-t) in SO.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean that I should set this option somewhere in my c code ?